# Securing Communication between App and Webservice by token

Tags: security, token, rsa

I am writing an android app that will communicate with a webserver.

So far, i got the communication basics and a token based authentication system.
The tokens are really long, but i am still afraid, someone could just guess them.
So i thought about something like the following. Is this a valid approach?

My Idea:

1. App generates RSA keypair.
2. Login with mail and password over ssl (provide public key to server)
3. Server generates unique token
4. Server saves token and public key
5. Server returns token to app
6. From now on, the app uses the token, but encrypts all messages with the private key.
7. Server receives message with token. It tries to decrypt the data with the public key, to make sure, this message is from the original login. If it couldn't decrypt, it declines the request.

Is this a valid approach? Or is this method too weak?

Comment: What is the problem or threat you are trying to solve or mitigate? What is the token actually used for in this design, is that a client identifier?

Comment: Exactly! I thought about using it as an identifier, like it is common with tokens in web-developement.
Finally I ran over Oauth2 with PKCE and chose to continue on that path, since it seems to be exactly what I tried to archive here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you want to do is a possible approach. Here some of my thoughts regarding your idea.

1. The chain is as strong as the weakest link. Have you thought about how you will reset the access when the user looses the device? Are credentials enough? Is access to the mailbox enough? The attacker will choose the easiest target.
2. Your approach looks suspiciously similar to [mutual authentication with TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication). Well, you can reinvent the wheel if you like, but I would probably stick to the standard. You don't want to solve the problem of e.g. reply attacks prevention, do you?
3. Why not simply use 2FA with TLS channel protection? [U2F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) for example is even stronger than having private client TLS keys lying around.
4. Encryption of long messages with RSA keys is slow. You usually encrypt only a symmetric key with RSA and the rest of the message with AES.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is very helpful and i will accept it as a solution.

It comes out, I invested more time on this, and finally chose to go with Oauth2 and PKCE, since this seems to do what I was looking for and has much more improvements.
No reason to reinvent the wheel, I guess.